# Does setting the length of the datatype matters if it is a view?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The original table's column is a varchar and the length is set as default in Snowflake which is 16,777,216, but in the final view it is limited to 25. which is causing some length errors while querying. I wonder if limiting this length in the final view is necessary as it is not going to store the physical data considering it is a view. What is the impact?

Expecting to ignore errors related to length of varchar.

Comment: You can but you will be in trouble if you want to use the view to load a table or use it to create a table.  I would proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

The SF documentation (for CREATE VIEW) explicitly states “You do not need to specify the data types of the columns”